# How to check multiconditions to concatenate an observable with rxjs

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I would like to make check condition on message which is an observable and to costumize the output like this scenerio :
check if the messsage is to me or from me and concatenate 20 first caracters with the **name of friend** or if it is my message with **you**
chech the type of message if it is a photo or file to make a message you sent an attament for example

```
getLastMessage(onlineUserModel: OnlineUserModel): Observable<string> {
    let message: Observable<string>;
   
    const messageModel = this.allDirectMessages$
      .pipe(
        map((x) =>
          x.filter(
            (f) =>
              f.messageModel.to.userName === onlineUserModel.userName ||
              f.messageModel.from.userName === onlineUserModel.userName
          )
        )
      )
      .pipe(map((data) => data[data.length - 1].messageModel))
      .pipe(
        map((item) => {
          if (item.to.userName == onlineUserModel.userName) {
            message = concat("You", item.content, "...");
          }
          else (item.to.userName == onlineUserModel.userName) {
            message = concat("You", item.content, "...");
          }
        })
      );

   
    return message;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return the message as an `Observable<string>` you can do something like this:

```
getLastMessage(onlineUserModel: OnlineUserModel): Observable<string> {   
  return this.allDirectMessages$
    .pipe(
      filter((f) =>
          f.messageModel.to.userName === onlineUserModel.userName ||
          f.messageModel.from.userName === onlineUserModel.userName
      ),
      map((data) => {
        const item = data[data.length - 1].messageModel;
        if (item.to.userName == onlineUserModel.userName) {
          return `You ${item.content}...`;
        }
        else (item.from.userName == onlineUserModel.userName) {
          return `Them ${item.content}...`;
        }
      })
    );
}
```

Comment: I find this Error Odd.....: Type 'Observable<Observable<string>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type 'Observable<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

Comment: I thought concat, was some function that just returned a string. I guess you get this error because you are importing `concat` from rxjs?

If you actually want the return type `Observable<string>` then you could instead return something like this:
`return 'you' + item.content + '...';` .

Please let me know if it works. I'll update the answer if it works for you.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**I try to share you my result, just I added the map operator before filter:**

```
getLastMessage(onlineUserModel: OnlineUserModel): Observable<string> {   
  return this.allDirectMessages$
    .pipe(
      filter((f) =>
          f.messageModel.to.userName === onlineUserModel.userName ||
          f.messageModel.from.userName === onlineUserModel.userName
      ),
      map((data) => {
        const item = data[data.length - 1].messageModel;
        if (item.to.userName == onlineUserModel.userName) {
          return `You ${item.content}...`;
        }
        else (item.from.userName == onlineUserModel.userName) {
          return `Them ${item.content}...`;
        }
      })
    );
}
```